# Error in UseMethod("predict') It keeps throwing an error

Tags: r

```
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "data.frame"
```

This is what i am trying to run to get predicted probabilities for validation dataset

```
fraud.predict <- predict(history.index, data = fraud.df, type = 'response')
```

Comment: As per the error, the `history.index` object can't be a data frame, but a model object used to draw predictions on new data. Without further information we cannot help you further.

Comment: In addition, you are passing a `data` argument which is most likely (I'm just venturing here...) not a named argument for the predict method of your model object class (which I'd bet is most likely one of `predict.lm`,  `predict.glm`). You are probably looking for `newdata`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.